Filament 3 - Restar dos TimePIcker
Estoy trabajando con Filament en su versión 3, tengo dos campos de tipo time (desde y hasta) y un campo canti_hr de tipo decimal (4,2), necesito restar horas y que me de un resultado en un entero o decimal desde: 10:00 hasta 12:30 canti_hr = 2.5, ademas validar que hasta sea siempre mayor a desde, he intentado esto, pero no lo logro.
               Forms\Components\TimePicker::make('desde')
                ->label('Hora Desde')
                ->default(now())
                ->format('%H:%i')
                ->withoutSeconds()
                ->live()
                ->reactive()
                ->afterStateUpdated(function (Get $get, Set $set) {
                    if ($get('desde') !== '' && $get('hasta') !== '') {
                        $desde= $get('desde');
                        $hasta= $get('hasta');                            
                        $desdetDateTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:', $desde);
                        $hastaDateTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $hasta);                           
                        $timeDifference = $hastaDateTime->diff($desdeDateTime)->format('%H:%I');
                        $set ('canti_hr', $timeDifference);
                    }
                })                   
                ->required(),
            Forms\Components\TimePicker::make('hasta')
                ->label('Hora Hasta')
                ->default(now())
                ->format('%H:%i')
                ->withoutSeconds()
                ->live()
                ->reactive()
                ->afterStateUpdated(function (Get $get, Set $set) {
                    if ($get('desde') !== '' && $get('hasta') !== '') {
  $desde= $get('desde');
                        $hasta= $get('hasta');                            
                        $desdetDateTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:', $desde);
                        $hastaDateTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $hasta);                           
                        $timeDifference = $hastaDateTime->diff($desdeDateTime)->format('%H:%I');
                        $set ('canti_hr', $timeDifference);
                    }
                })

                ->required(),   
            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('canti_hr')                            
                ->label('Cantidad Horas')     
                ->suffixIcon('heroicon-m-clock')
                ->rules('required')
                ->readOnly() 
                ->dehydrated()
                ->numeric()                    
                ->required(),

